# react native: function not returning react component

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I'm building a DnD app for character sheet management, where it displays the skills and whatnot.
In it I have a class(*AbiltityClass*) that stores a map of other classes(*SkillClass*) inside of a variable(*_aSkills*).

```
export default class AbilityClass {

    constructor(name, aVal, aMod) {
        this._abilityName = name; // string
        this._abilityVal = aVal; // int
        this._abilityMod = aMod; // int
        this._aSkills = new Map(); // map of SkillClass objects
    }
}


export default class SkillClass {

    constructor(name, prof, mod, bonus){
        this._nameSkill = name; // string
        this._profSkill = prof; // bool
        this._modBonus = bonus; // int
        this._modSkill = this.evalMod(mod); // int
    }
    
    evalMod(mod) {
        return mod + this._modBonus;
    }
}
```

The *_aSkills* variable was originally an Array of *SkillClass*es, but due to ease-of-accessing, I decided that a Map would be better.

I have a process that will basically iterate through each element in *_aSkills* and create components out of them through the *skillFactory* and *buildSkill* functions which should be placed in the brackets where the *skillFactory* function is called.

```
const AbilityContainer = (props) => {

  const buildSkill = (value, key) => {
    return(
      <SkillSet
        key={Math.random()}
        skillName={key}
        prof={value._profSkill}
        skillVal={value._modSkill}
        setProf={()=>{}}
      />
    );
  }
  
  const skillFactory = () => {
    return(props.ability._aSkills.forEach(buildSkill));
  }

  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.header_text}>
          {props.ability._abilityName}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.statBox}>
        <View style={styles.ability}>
          <StackedHex isAbility={true} lowerVal={props.ability._abilityVal}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.skills}>
          {skillFactory()}   // =================> The function call in question
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

My issue is that either *skillFactory* or *buildSkill* is not returning the *SkillSet* component.
I've used some print logs and I've verified that *buildSkill* is receiving the correct data, but something isn't working. I don't get any errors or warnings, and the place where the *SkillSet* components should be is just empty.
As I said, I changed the *_aSkills* variable from an Array to a Map recently, and it was working as an Array. This is the format of my previous code:

```
const AbilityContainer = (props) => {

  const buildSkill = (skill) => {
    return(
      <SkillSet
        key = {Math.random()}
        prof={skill._profSkill}
        setProf={skill._profFunc}
        skillName={skill._nameSkill}
        skillVal={skill._modSkill}
      />
    );
  }

  const skillFactory = () => {
    return (props.ability._aSkills.map(x => buildSkill(x)));
  }

  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.header_text}>
          {props.ability._abilityName}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.statBox}>
        <View style={styles.ability}>
          <StackedHex isAbility={true} lowerVal={props.ability._abilityVal}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.skills}>
          <SkillSet 
            prof={props.ability._saveProf}
            setProf={props.ability._saveProfFunc}
            skillName={'Save'}
            skillVal={props.ability._saveMod}
            />
          {skillFactory()}
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I'm using Android Studio for this build and I'm still relatively new to react-native. I triple-checked all my other components and their stylesheets to make sure they weren't interfering, so I know it has something to do with the *AbilityContainer*.
I've read up on the forEach function for Maps and as far as I can tell, I'm doing it right, but I feel like there is something that forEach is doing that I don't understand in terms of how it returns things.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` does something for each element, but doesn't return anything (even if you return in the callback, that's just returning from the cb, not the equivalent of returning from a `.map`) which is why that version isn't working. If you convert it back to an array (`[...props.ability._aSkills].map...`) this will give you an array of arrays ([key, value]) from your Map. You could also use a `for..of` loop over `_aSkills.entries()`.

Comment: This helped. I guess I didn't fully understand how forEach worked.

Answer (score 0):

So now knowing that forEach doesn't return anything, I just added a variable and gave my *buildSkill* function something to return to.

Here's what I did:

```
const AbilityContainer = (props) => {
  let skills = new Array();

  const buildSkill = (value, key) => {
      skills.push(<SkillSet
        key={Math.random()}
        skillName={key}
        prof={value._profSkill}
        skillVal={value._modSkill}
        setProf={()=>{}}
      />);
  }
  
  const skillFactory = () => {
    props.ability._aSkills.forEach(buildSkill);
    return(skills);
  }
... 
};
```